# Border wont be 100% height

Tags: html, css

I have this following HTML code:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="float:left; height:900px;">
<div class="inbox"></div>

<div class="message">
    <div style="width:100%; border-bottom:1px #ddd solid; height:38px;"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

and css

```
.inbox {
    height: 100%;
    width: 215px;
    border-bottom:none;
    border-top:none;
    border-left: 1px #ddd solid;
    border-right: 1px #ddd solid;
    margin-left:50px;
    float: left;
}
#inbox {
text-decoration: none;
    color:#444;
}

.message {
width:392px;
height:100%;
float: left;

}
```

As you can see inbox has a border in both sides. I woul like to make these boders go from the top of the wrapper to the bottom, but i wont. It just goes as long as data inside the inbox div is..

I hope you understand my question, Best regards Emil

Comment: `min-height: 100%`? Could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Here's a fiddle, OP could probably provide a better one, but this has the code provided above... http://jsfiddle.net/CBx99/

Comment: Set padding from inbox to zero

Comment: According to this fiddle the border goes the entire height of the `.wrapper` div. Am I missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/xcBaE/

Comment: Or the maring of the wrapper to zero